# Git and IntelliJ terminal for 2020.1

Tags: git, intellij-idea, terminal

I am trying to set the Terminal of IntelliJ from the default to Git. 
I have set in Version Control->Git the path to git:
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe

I have set in Tools->Terminal the path to:
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i

I have also tried to set it to:
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe

with/without quotes, without --login -i, restarted intelliJ million times but my terminal is not showing anything.
I have also checked under Settings->Plugins and Terminal is installed. I only have blinking pointer and can not type anything there
[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z5yA.png)

I am using IntelliJ 2020.1 and git 2.20.1. Does anyone have idea how to fix this?

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` should work (works for me). Are there any errors in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)? Proofs: https://i.imgur.com/8kXQe8O.png
https://i.imgur.com/HMu9D8B.png.

Comment: No, not any errors. This was working fine on my old machine with IntelliJ 2018.2.5 but this version is no longer available so I assuming something else needs to be configured or to use older versions of git and IntelliJ?

Comment: If you check with the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer the tree, what do you see there? Is there bash.exe process under idea64.exe? See https://i.imgur.com/MbWSfi4.png. Do you have any anitivirus/firewall running that may block IntelliJ IDEA from starting a process? Windows Even Log may have the details about it: https://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/ .

Comment: I do have corporate policies that might block something, but not showing it. Here how it looks like https://pasteboard.co/JclQyUi.png

I have checked event log, many errors there but not very descriptive, for example, many times
A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10011.

Comment: So it doesn't look like bash.exe is executed. Are you sure there is nothing about it in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)? You may want to contact your IT helpdesk to help you whitelist it.

Comment: In meantime I notice one more problem with this version of IntelliJ, on each executed test it is automatically start building so instead on 15 sec, each test took me 4-5min even if I did not change anything in code. So I downgraded to version 2019.2 on which I did not had any issue with git terminal. 
Thank you for your time